# Get programmatically value of sub field collection item of a field collection

Tags: stream-wrappers

I have a field collection

field library

and a sub field collection

field book

which has a  field collection item field title.

to get the first field collection I use a wrapper:

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

foreach ($node_wrapper->field_library->value() as $key => 
$field_collection_wrapper) {
$ffp = $field_collection_wrapper->field_title[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
}
```

but I need another for each inside the first foreach to get the item of the sub collection.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this should be structured properly. It should give you access to each book on each library item.

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$libraries = $node_wrapper->field_library->value();
foreach($libraries as $library){
  $library_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $library);
  $books = $library_wrapper->field_book->value();
  foreach($books as $book){
    $book_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $book);
    $title = $book_wrapper->field_title->value();
  }
}
```